# How can I find the system PATH in linux for any executable? (ubuntu distro)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have tried using the command: **echo $PATH**, but I get a path that I do not recognize as an actual directory on my machine:

"/home/user_name/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

If I want to install a new program into the correct directory, how can I find the system PATH using the Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Well, these are the paths. Executables (Binary or Scripts with executable bit and valid bang-path) need to be placed there to be able to be executed without prepending a specific location.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you do not understand UNIX paths at all.

"/home/user_name/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

Means:

```
/home/user_name/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

and so on.

The colon : is used to **separate** paths when concatenating them within a string! So, in contrast to "windows" C:foo would mean: two paths (C and foo in the Unix/Linux world)

And I am pretty sure that all these different paths exist on your system.

And for that other implied question: determining the **correct** directory for a new executable might very much depend on your that new thing.

When you wrote a little script for yourself, you would typically put it into ~/bin. But things that should be used by other users might go to /usr/local/bin for example. For more details on that part; turn to the "duplicated" question suggested to you